# Make a middle clicked link open in a new tab to the immediate right of the tab which contained the link

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

In Firefox, a middle clicked link opens a new tab right at the end of the tab list, which is usually at the far right of the window. When you have a lot of tabs, this can mean the new tab is 10 or 15 positions away from the tab that spawned it.

I want to to be able to middle click on a given link in a tab and have a new tab open to the immediate right of the tab I'm currently in.

Is there any configuration setting or extension that allows me to get this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox's "Tab Mix Plus" add-on allows this.

From Firefox: Click on `Tools` > `Tab Mix Plus options...`

From Tab Mix Plus: Click `Events` > `Tab Opening`

...and select `Open other tabs next to the current one`.

Answer (score 3):

As of Firefox v 3.6 opening a link in a new tab opens the tab immediately to the right of the current one. It's the only way this works now, I can't find an option on the user interface that controls it.

Both right click & "Open Link in New Tab" and middle click work this way.

Comment: You can change it using `about:config` and `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent`

Comment: [Ctrl + Click] Also works this way. Note that this does *not* apply to new tabs opened through ways such as [Ctrl + t], the "Open a new tab" toolbar button, or typing in the location or search bar and pressing [Alt + Enter].

Answer (score 1):

You can make Firefox give focus to the newly opened tab, rather than having to search for it.

This feature is built-in to Firefox already, go to: Tools > Options > Tabs > Tick 'When I open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately'

The [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122) add-on may have the functionality you want, I dont use Firefox though so cannot test/confirm this.

Comment: Tab Mix Plus does indeed have the functionality desired. Go to the add-on's Preferences->Events->Tab Opening. Check the box titled "Open other tabs next to current one".

Answer (score 1):

The description of the Firefox add-on [Tabberwocky](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14439) says:

> Open tabs to the right of current tab

but as I haven't tried it, I don't know if you can attache this to middle click.