# In firefox how to open new tab near just next to current tab?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a middle clicked link open in a new tab to the immediate right of the tab which contained the link](https://superuser.com/questions/88485/make-a-middle-clicked-link-open-in-a-new-tab-to-the-immediate-right-of-the-tab-wh)

In firefox how to open new tab just next to current tab? By default it opens at last.

is it possible without any plugin

I'm using firefox 3.5.2

Comment: Yet another dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/88485/make-a-middle-clicked-link-open-in-a-new-tab-to-the-immediate-right-of-the-tab-wh

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Firefox are you running?

I've just tried this in v 3.6 and it opens the tab immediately to the right of the current one. It seems to be the default behaviour now, I can't find an option in the user interface that controls it.

Both right click & "Open Link in New Tab" and middle click work this way.

I haven't got any tab related extensions installed at the moment.

It's certainly worth keeping your browser (what ever browser you use) up to date with the latest version - if nothing else you'll be kept as secure as is possible from vulnerabilities in the code.

Comment: open lot of tabs then go to first tab and try to open any link in new tab it will open at last

Comment: I get the same behaviour as Chris in FF 3.6, also without any tab-related extensions. Can you confirm what version you are using?

Comment: i'm using 3.5.2

Comment: @Jitendra vyas - upgrade to 3.6

Comment: In FF3.6, one can change this using `about:config` and `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent`

Comment: actually the correct `about:config` option is `browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent`  `.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` only deals with opening tabs from url links while browsing an existing tab.  `insertAfterCurrent` will open a new tab next to current tab with `Ctrl + T` or any new tab command.  see [this article](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/05/10/open-tabs-in-firefox-to-the-right-of-the-current-tab/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is, but if you're using FF without extensions, you're missing the major draw.

Tab Mix Plus can do this, along with a lot more.