# Firefox shortcut for opening a new tab near to the current tab

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

I use `Mozilla Firefox 92.0`. I am looking for a **shortcut** to open new tab just next to the current tab? By default it opens at last.

- I did not find any thing in `about:preferences` of Firefox
- I looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/q/103731/140047); but I think it is wrongly marked as duplicate: *This question already has answers*
- I also looked at [this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly); but I could not find any thing there

Note:

I know I can right click on tab title and select `new tab`. But it needs using mouse. Although it may help if I know how I can select  the tab title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox has a built-in setting
(`about:config` item `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent`)
to automatically open tabs next to the current tab, but it only works
when clicking a link inside the current tab, and will then open that tab
next to the current one.
But if you click the `New` button or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>,
it will always add the new tab at the end of all the tabs.

To change the the way that New-Tab works, install the add-on
[Open Tabs Next to Current](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/open-tabs-next-to-current/).

A non-add-on way is to use the bookmarklet described
[here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=528005#c53):

```
javascript:window.open('about:blank');void(0);
```

Click the bookmarklet in the Bookmarks Toolbar or assign it a keyword
to open a new tab after the current one.

Comment: I selected the `bookmarklet` way.

Answer (score 24):

**Firefox v=102** has a built-in setting called `browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent`.

If you set it to `true` using `about:config` you will get what you are looking for, using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will open a tab to the right of the current one.

I think that setting has been available for a few versions now, probably since at least version 86, maybe much earlier.

Comment: Curios, how to open new tabs on the left side?

Comment: @EugenKonkov The best way to do this would be to use a setting like `browser.tabs.insertBeforeCurrent` but such a setting currently doesn´t exist. You could use the method I posted and then move the tab to the left using the hotkey (Alt+Shift+Left) available in the [Move Tab Hotkeys extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/move-tab-hotkeys/)

Comment: This always opens all tabs after the current, even when I do not want that! I dislike that.

Comment: Do you know how to open a link next to the current tab? When I open a link using `Cmd + click`, it opens further to the right if the current tab, for example, is in the middle

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a shortcut. You can set this up in the config. My fellow writers have already mentioned something similar, but below is a more detailed step-by-step guide on setting it up as a default.

1. Open Firefox Browser on your computer.
2. In the address bar, type `about:config` and press Enter. This will take you to Firefox's advanced settings page.
3. You may see a warning stating that changing advanced settings can affect Firefox's functionality. Click on the "Accept the Risk and Continue" button to proceed.
4. In the search bar at the top of the page, type `browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent`.
5. You should see a preference named `browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent`. By default, its value is set to `true`, which means new tabs are opened at the end of all tabs.
6. To change this behavior and open new tabs immediately next to the current tab you're working on, double-click on the preference `browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent` to toggle its value to `false`.
7. Once you've changed the value to false, close the `about:config` tab.
8. Now, when you open a new tab by clicking on the 'plus' symbol or using the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), it should open immediately next to the current tab you're working on.